# List comprehension for flatteing values from dicts from list

Tags: python, ruby, arrays

I want to get a one-dimensional list of values from several keys for list of dicts.

That's how I do it in Ruby:

```
irb> list_ = [{a:1, b:2, c:3}, {a:4, b:5, c:6}]

irb> list_.flat_map{ |dict_| dict_.values_at :b, :c }
=> [2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Now how I do it in Python?

Comment: @Charles, let me ask: what was wrong with that tag? And why so I see "4 subscribers" to it, but no questions exist.

Comment: `one-liner` is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).  Tag subscriptions survive tag deletion.  You wouldn't believe the number of people subscribed to my eternal nemesis tag, `server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
>>> lst = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}]
>>> [dct[i] for dct in lst for i in ('b', 'c')]
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: +1 This is elegant and almost twice as fast than my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain,imap

>>> lis = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}]

>>> list(chain.from_iterable((x[y] for y in ('b','c')) for x in lis))
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

or list comprehension version (less memory efficient):

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable([x[y] for y in ('b','c')] for x in lis))
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

As suggested by [jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219006/jamylak) you can also use `operator.itemgetter` and `itertools.imap` with `itertools.chain`, which is even faster than the [LC version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16396457/846892) used by [Volatility](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1907098/volatility).

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(imap(itemgetter('b', 'c'), lis)))
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Timing:

```
>>> lis = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}]*10**5

>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable((x[y] for y in ('b','c')) for x in lis))
1 loops, best of 3: 276 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable([x[y] for y in ('b','c')] for x in lis))
1 loops, best of 3: 183 ms per loop

>>> %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(imap(itemgetter('b', 'c'), lis))) #winner
10 loops, best of 3: 74.6 ms per loop

>>> %timeit [dct[i] for dct in lis for i in ('b', 'c')]  
10 loops, best of 3: 98.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: You can remove the unnecessary brackets from the generator one, they serve no purpose. Also try timing `list(chain.from_iterable(imap(itemgetter('b', 'c'), lst)))` It gets pretty close to the list comp (actually beats it by `1ms` on my system.

Comment: @jamylak It's even faster than LC version.

Comment: I should have also mentioned, I made a quick edit from `map` to `imap`, try that too ;)

Comment: @jamylak you should post it as your own answer. :)

Comment: It's only a slight variant of yours and it's just to check the speed, I wouldn't recommend it as a solution though